# Retrieving client port number from Pam module

Tags: linux, pam, sshd

How do I retrieve an SSH client's port number from a PAM module? 
I can get the client host from `PAM_RHOST`:

```
retval = pam_get_item(pamh, PAM_RHOST, (const void **) &rhost);
```

It is present in the SSHD logs, but I am not sure how to extract it.

Comment: Are you able to see the `SSH_CONNECTION` environment variable when in your PAM module?

Comment: There is no api to get client port number from pam and SSH_CONNECTION gets populated once the pam returns Authentication success. You can use SSH_CONNECTION to extract client port number,  once your pam authentication is successful.